# NSTableview won't sort in Core Data application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, nstableview

I've got a Core Data application with an NSTableView and the columns are hooked up to an arrayController. Problem is, when I click the tabs at the top of the table to sort the contents nothing happens.

My bindings look like this:

[image: bindings]

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected **Create Sort Descriptor** on the Value binding for those columns?

Comment: Would you know how to get this to sort automatically when the web view is loaded? I'm really stuck here!

Comment: Would you post a new question?